# 100kHz Downconverter conversion

Tags: mixer

I've got a 900MHz downconverter design which I'm trying to convert for a 100kHz single ended RF input and LO input. I'm not sure how to calculate the required capacitor and inductor values, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image: 900MHz Downconverting Mixer]

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be pushing the data sheet to extremes for a frequency of 100kHz. The nearest circuit in the data sheet that matches your requirements is this: -

[image]

This down converts to 450kHz and uses an op-amp on the output so immediately you don't need to worry about a bunch of inductors - just use the op-amp instead for servicing your needs. Should you require additional filtering - use more op-amp stages.

The above circuit down converts at 90MHz using a 90.45MHz local oscillator - the two remaining inductors are there to match impedances for the RF input. At 100kHz just use an op-amp to drive IN+ and don't worry about matching at all because at this frequency it just won't matter - the input op-amp I mentioned needs to be reasonably fast and feed it's output to the IN+ via something like a 220R resistor.

Comment: @Shane feel free to accept the answer if you think it's useful but maybe wait another day (or so) to see if anyone else answers.